# Embed Julia in C -- cflags and ldflags

Tags: makefile, julia

How does one portably find cflags and ldflags of a julia install to pass to a C compiler?

I am trying to embed Julia in a C application. Right now I can hardcode julia libraries in the compile line, but I would prefer to find a mechanism that is a bit more portable.

Here is my current Makefile which require the julia executable to be pointing into the source directory.

```
JULIA_BIN = $(shell dirname `which julia`)
JULIA_PATH = $(JULIA_BIN)/../..
JULIA_LIBDIR = $(JULIA_PATH)/usr/lib
JULIA_CFLAGS = -I$(JULIA_PATH)/src -I$(JULIA_PATH)/src/support I$(JULIA_PATH)/include/julia -I$(JULIA_PATH)/usr/include
JULIA_LDFLAGS = -L$(JULIA_LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(JULIA_LIBDIR) -ljulia

$(LIBTD_JULIA): td.h td_julia.c $(LIBTD)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) -fPIC -c td_julia.c -o td_julia.o $(JULIA_CFLAGS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) -shared -fPIC td_julia.o -o $@ $(JULIA_LDFLAGS) ./$(LIBTD)
```

Comment: Oh, it would be lovely if julia was able to indicate suggested compiler flags itself. R has something alike, e.g. you may call `R CMD config --cppflags`. If nothing like that is available in julia (I don't know that, sorry), maybe consider posting a feature request?

Comment: Yeah python has `python-config --cflags`.  I've emailed the devs but posted here while I wait for their response in case it is possible and others knew how to do it.